# ServiceStack Dump() of base class

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack-text

I use ServiceStack's Dump() in logs to dump whole object to the console, however I just noticed that when the object in question is cast to a base class then only those class properties will be serialized. Is there any way to to serialize the full class? I looked for an overload with a type parameter which would allow me to do something like `obj.Dump(obj.GetType())` but it doesn't exist.

Is there a way to serialize that object? I know there a lot of different options to log to console but I used this primarily for the simplicity and ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

You can down cast it to an object where it will use the runtime type instead:

```
((object)obj).Dump();
```

Comment: I tried this but it still serializes to an empty object. Json.NET works fine with this object by the way.